# Google sheets boolean issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some mysterious issue in sheets. I've copied same code in different sheets and most of them return false when the condition in separate cell returns true.

Do you have any idea on this case?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The formula you use will search in each cell of column J the character `-` in the corresponding row of column G
- So, in cell `J2` it will be evaluated either cell `G2` contians a `-`, cell `J3` does the same for `G3` and so on.
- If `-` is found - the function `search` will return the position of the character (a number)
- If `-` is not found, the function will return the error `#VALUE!` (not a number)
- This is why your final formula will return you `true` or `false` depending on either `-` has been found in the respective row of column `G` or not